# Laravel Ajax update request is duplicating data

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to update data using ajax, but my data is being duplicated,
due to ajax URL, i am not sure if i am passing correctly/

**Ajax Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
$('#update-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",      

 url: "teachers/" + $('#update-id').attr("value"), //error is here

            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),

            success: function (data) {

                alert("updated");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**view code:**

i have table with list of teachers, and edit button for each teacher;

```
<button type="button" id="btn" value="{{ $teacher->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm edit-btn">Edit</button>
```

in form i have hidden field

```
<form method="post" id="update-form">
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        <input type="hidden" id="update-id" value="{{$teacher->id}}" >

            <div class="">
                <label for="efirst">efirst</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="efirst" id="update-efirst">
                <textarea name="esecond" class="form-control" id="update-esecond" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  id="update-submit">Update</button>
        </form>
```

when i click on update, teacher ID's are being changed, one teacher id becomes another teacher id. is it correct way to pass teacher id from hidden field?

Comment: show me your form html code

Comment: @RiponUddin please check form added

Comment: What happens when you click the Edit button?

Comment: it shows data in form, each teacher have different data on edit button. which is working fine

Comment: @iMatti add {{ csrf_field() }} after form tag start

Comment: i think ID is not updating when i go from one edit to another edit.

Comment: can u show me your route which u wrote at web.php

Comment: @RiponUddin i can see teachers json data on teachers/123 and teacher/123/edit

Comment: 123 is example, which is id of each teacher

Comment: @RiponUddin  above code is updating next record in table, leaving current record which i am updating.

Comment: if i do paginate 1 to show one record in table, then id 1 record is being updated, if i show 2 records, then if i update id 1, then id 2 is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Write route name like below

At Web.php

```
Route::post("teacher/{id}/edit","YourController")->name("teacher.update");
```

At Blade File

```
$('#update-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#update-id').val(); // $('#update-id').attr("value") also ok
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",  
        url: "{{ route('teacher.update',id) }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("updated");
        },
    });
});
```

Try this. 
It will be work

Comment: if i do paginate 1 to show one record in table, then id 1 record is being updated, if i show 2 records, then if i update id 1, then id 2 is being updated.

Comment: <form method="post" id="update-form" action="{{ route('teacher.update',$teacher->id) }}"> and no need to declare any hidden field inside form and change url : $(this).attr("action"),

Comment: app.js:10216 POST http://isp.local/teachers/%20http://isp.local/teachers/208 404 (Not Found)